# Specialize hashmap template

Tags: c++, templates, hash, hashmap, std

I'm using the hash_map in C++ and want to supply a simplified type name for it:

The key type and hasher function are always the same.

```
stdext::hash_map<std::string, [MAPPED TYPE], CStringHasher>
```

However, I don't really want to write all this every time I declare a hash map which maps strings to type X.

- Can I write a template or macro that simplifies this?

So the above declaration would look like:

```
template<typename T> StringHashmap = stdext::hash_map<std::string, T, CStringHasher>

StringHashmap<int> mapA; //Maps std::string to int
StringHashamp<bool> mapB; //Maps std::string to bool
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others said, template aliases is the way to go if you can use C++0x:

```
template < typename MappedType >
using StringHashMap = stdext::hash_map< std::string, MappedType, CStringHasher >;

StringHashMap< int > mapA;
StringHashMap< bool > mapB;
```

(As @MSalters noted, if you have C++0x available, you should probably use `std::unordered_map`.)

Otherwise, you can still use the usual workaround, which is to define a class template containing a typedef:

```
template < typename MappedType >
struct StringHashMap
{
    typedef stdext::hash_map< std::string, MappedType, CStringHasher > type;
};

StringHashMap< int >::type mapA;
StringHashMap< bool >::type mapB;
```

A drawback with this solution (which have engendered **many** questions here on SO) is that you sometimes need to prefix `StringHashMap< T >::type` by the `typename` keyword in order to assert to the compiler that this name effectively denotes a type. I will not dwell on this subject in this answer, you can check out [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names), and especially the accepted answer, for more information. (Thanks to @sbi for evoking this matter.)

Comment: +1 This is a much better answer than mine.  I'm going to have to remember this trick.

Comment: Note that `StringHashMap<T>::type` needs to be qualified as a type name when used in a template where `T` is (or is dependent from) a template parameter: `typename StringHashMap<T>::type`. There is an [FAQ entry for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245) on SO. You might want to spend some words on this issue. Nevertheless, `+1` for a good answer.

Comment: If you had C++0x, you'd be using `std::unordered_map` instead of `stdext::hash_map`.

Comment: @sbi @MSalters: I edited the answer to include your remarks, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of C++ (C++03), there really isn't a good way to do this.  You could try something like

```
#define StringHashMap(type) stdext::hash_map<std::string, type, CStringHasher>
```

But then you run into trouble if you try to specify a template type with a comma in it, like this:

```
StringHashMap(pair<int, string>) myMap; // Error!
```

This fails because the preprocessor will tokenize this as

```
StringHashMap((pair<int), (string>)) myMap; // Error!
```

which isn't what you want.  If you're not going to do anything like this, though, you should be fine.  You could alternatively use `typedef`s to get around it:

```
typedef pair<int, int> IntPair;
StringHashMap(IntPair) myMap; // Okay
```

If you're allowing use of C++0x features, you can use a template using declaration, like this one here:

```
template <typename T>
    using StringHashMap = stdext::hash_map<std::string, T, CStringHasher>;
```

Unfortunately, C++03 doesn't have a "template typedef" feature like this one, so you'd have to use a newer compiler and won't have as good a portability guarantee.

Hey, wait a minute!  My name is `templatetypedef` and this is the first time on Stack Overflow that I've ever written that phrase in an answer!  You just made my night. :-)

Comment: +1 for having the appropriate user-name to be answering this question.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `<T>` after `StringHashMap` in the using declaration. Good remarks about the issue of commas in macro arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C++ 0x, template typedefs were designed to do exactly this kind of thing:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Template_aliases